# How to Test performance of Graphql API

Tags: rest, jmeter, graphql, web-api-testing

I want to test the performance of graphics API, but Jmeter shows me the error of 400(Bad request) every time.

what I am doing is this:-

1.Created an Http Header Manager and provided respective content type and tokens

2.Created an HTTP Request

In Body:- Provided Graphql query(formatted query which postman accept)
3.Added a Listener

Every time it is showing Bad request but the same process works fine with Postman.

Please help.

Comment: There is some issue in the jmeter request. Compare the send request from Postman and jmeter. It may be some parsing issue. Though, I have not worked with Graphql, so consider it a way of debugging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

If your requests works fine in Postman you can just record it with JMeter

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature.

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording" and click "Create"
   - Click [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and press "Start"

   [image: JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder from Template]
2. Prepare Postman for recording. Configure it to use JMeter as a [Global Proxy](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/proxy)

   [image: JMeter Postman Proxy]
3. Execute your test in Postman
4. JMeter will capture the request and store it under Thread Group -> [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)